# Best practice to show or hide "premium features" based on user state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication

I have a rails backend for user authentication and handling payments through Stripe. I'm building a web app that has three different tiers of functionaility: guest users, logged in users and premium users.

Upon authentication the backend sends a user object to my react frontend which is stored in the state of my `app.js` class.

```
user: {
  created_at: "2020-09-14T15:28:34.397Z",
  email: "yo@test.com",
  id: 14,
  password_digest: "blablabla",
  premium: true,
  updated: "2020-09-14T15:37:41.648Z"
}
```

As you can see it holds the `premium: true` variable. It gets set in rails after a successful payment.

Because it is my first time implementing "premium functionaliy" I am not sure what the best practice is to prevent users from interacting with certain features of the application if their `premium` is set to `false`.

Do I just check for it when rendering components like this?

```
if(this.state.user.premium) {
  // show premium features
} else {
  // hide premium features
}
```

This is what I would do but doesn't this allow anyone with the react developer tools to edit the object in their browser so they can just set it to true? I would be very grateful for any insight how to achieve this in the cleanest way possible.

Comment: I would consider adding [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) to the server side to handle authorization (who gets to do what). Authorization is really a server side concern as you can't prevent clients from sending any request they want to when used by a malicious user.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the frontend world  You can't hide this features because the logic is implemented in a code that you send to the user (so keep in mind that he has full control on it even if you make it difficult using a minifier and an uglyfier). So technically, an user can see and make appear the hidden `Delete Database` button. So the only think that you need to make really safe is your backend. User can click on the button and send the `deleteDb` request, but if you check the permissions of the sender of the request, you will notice that he doesn't have any permissions. So you don't execute the request.

So in your case, user could have access to the `premium` frontend-section, but what matter is that he never get any infos from `premium` from your backend ;)